# sql update multiple values to one column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables.

table_a      table_b

idA         idB
nameA       nameB
remarkA1    remarkB
remarkA2

Update from Comment: Code I have tired

```
UPDATE table_b 
SET remarkB = table_a.remarkA1 
FROM table_a WHERE table_b.id = table_a.id
```

But this code I can only update one value to column remarkB,If i want update values in `table_b` from `table_a` by update values from
`remarkA1`, `remarkA2` to `remarkB`  How should I write?

Comment: Does both the tables have any connection? How are the two tables linked to each other? Any query which you have tried?

Comment: @Gone the table don't have connection.
I tired yo update by 

UPDATE table_b
SET remarkB = table_a. remarkA1
FROM table_a
WHERE table_b.id = table_a.id

But this code i can update one value to column remarkB,
 if I want remarkB have two value from remarkA1 , remarkA2 .
I can write or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following Update Statement along with you need a string `CONCAT`

I'm assuming the data type of `table_a.remarkA1` and `table_a.remarkA2` are string (i.e., `VARCHAR`)

```
UPDATE table_b
SET remarkB = CONCAT(table_a.remarkA1, ' ', table_a.remarkA2)
FROM table_a
WHERE table_b.idB = table_a.idA
```

Comment: Thank you,but i use SQL server 2008 r2. 
It's can't use concat .What can i do ?

Comment: @Bear_Seul - you can try  `SELECT {fn concat (table_a.remarkA1, table_a.remarkA2)};` in previous versions. Only accepts 2 parameters though

Comment: use `table_a.remarkA1 +  ' ' +  table_a.remarkA2` in part of the CONCAT